# Using git from openshift

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, ssh-keys

git is great as an storage solution (in fact, it is a content-addressable filesystem) so I was thinking about using it for storing data (basically log files) from an OpenShift app. I have not tried, but I guess that it could be used via username/password storing these as a local variable. However, I would like to use it via ssh in the usual way. The problem is that I have found that the `.ssh` directory can't be written to and there is no way to store private ssh keys in a particular application. Setting up agent forwarding apparently also requires editing `.ssh/config` and I'm out of solutions here. Any other way? Or should I directly use HTTPS access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You SHOULD not use git for storing log files.

### Why?

Since git take snapshot of each changes file, snapshot means that it actually storing the original file. In your case each log file will be a new file in git !!! which will cause your repository to become HUGE repository (file system size) in a very short time.

You should consider storing your logs in a different way. (like zip them [git zip them as well])

Comment: I'm not saying I'm using it to store different versions of a file, just to store files as an external filesystem, much in the same way I would use Dropbox or some other cloud storage solution. Which might be an alternative, but I haven't found an easy way to use a dropbox client from an application either.

Comment: I second what @jsexpert has said.  It would make more sense to use dropbox or amazon s3 for remote storage, you can interact with them using their respective API's.